# Composing validating functions in Scala

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

Suppose I need to write a validating function `Validate[A]`:

```
type Status[A] = Validation[List[String], A]
type Validate[A] = A => Status[A] // should be Kleisli
```

The function returns either a `Success` with the input if the input is valid or a `Failure` with the list of errors if it is not.

For example,

```
val isPositive: Validate[Int] = {x: Int =>
  if (x > 0) x.success else List(s"$x is not positive").failure 
}

val isEven: Validate[Int] = {x: Int =>
  if (x % 2 == 0) x.success else List(s"$x is not even").failure
}
```

Since `Validation` is a semigroup `Validate` is semigroup too and (if I define it as `Kleisli`) I can *compose* validating functions as follows:

```
val isEvenPositive = isEven |+| isPositive
```

Suppose now that I need to validate `X`:

```
case class X(x1: Int, // should be positive 
             x2: Int) // should be even
```

Since `Validation` is an applicative functor `Validate` is an applicative functor too.

```
val x: Validate[X] = (isPositive |@| isEven)(X.apply)
```

Does it make sense ?

Comment: Validation only forms a semigroup where both left and right form semigroups

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I thought `Validation[E, A]` _requires_ `E` to be a semigroup but it probably does not.

Comment: It requires `E: Semigroup` to form an applicative and it requires `E: Semigroup, A: Semigroup` to form a semigroup. See [ValidationInstances](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.0/doc/scalaz/ValidationInstances.html)

Comment: Not a duplicate but somewhat related and might lead to a different approach: http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

You can compose validations when the left hand type is a semigroup. Your List works, but scalaz provides a built in `type ValidationNel[L, R] = Validation[NonEmptyList[L], R]` which you should use instead. There's several convenience functions like `aValidation.toValidationNel` for lifting values with single errors. The composed Validation will have a left hand side with all failures accumulated or a right hand with the success applied to your function

```
def foo: ValidationNel[String, Int]
def bar: ValidationNel[String, Double]
val composed: ValidationNel[String, Double] = foo(input) |@| bar(input) apply { (i: Int, d: Double) => i * d }
```

If you're looking for composition to a new single function in the shape of (`V` as shorthand for `Validation`)

```
(A => V[L, B], A => V[L, C]) => (A => V[L, (B, C)])
```

Then I'm not quite sure of the right way. It feels like there should be a combinator or two that would do just this but I haven't found it.

I have managed to write this composition, but I feel like there might be a better way.

```
  def composeV[A, B, C, L: Semigroup](f: A => Validation[L, B], g: A => Validation[L, C]): A => Validation[L, (B, C)] = {
    import scalaz.syntax.arrow._
    import scalaz.syntax.apply._
    import scalaz.std.function.function1Instance
    val oneInput: (A) => (Validation[L, B], Validation[L, C]) = f &&& g
    oneInput andThen {
      case (vb, vc) =>
        vb |@| vc apply { case x: (B, C) => x }
    }
  }
```

Here's another way:

```
def composeV[A, B, C, L: Semigroup](f: A => Validation[L, B], g: A => Validation[L, C]): A => Validation[L, (B, C)] = {
  import scalaz.syntax.apply._
  import scalaz.std.function.function1Instance
  f |@| g apply { case (vb, vc) =>
    vb |@| vc apply { case x: (B, C) => x }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am wondering how to compose _functions_ that return `Validation`. I think that since those functions are `Kleisli` we can compose them _exactly_ as `Validation` values. That's why I have asked this question.

Comment: @Michael I've just managed to write one. I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: I still think that since my `Validate` is `Kleisli` (I have updated the question) I get such a composition _for free_.

Comment: @Michael I agree, I think you can, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Ok, now I feel like I should go to REPL and try to code the solution _for real_ instead of asking in SO :)

Comment: @Michael I look forward to your answer, I've had this floating in my head for weeks without clicking on the right way

Comment: Sorry, cannot figure it out :( Maybe I will ask another question about that ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Maybe something with `tuple` from apply syntax

Comment: Added a new question with another solution. You are welcome to check.