# How to compose functions that return Applicative in point-free style?

Tags: scalaz, applicative, pointfree

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568926/how-to-compose-functions-that-return-validation):

Suppose I have a few functions that return `scalaz.Validaton`:

```
type Status[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]

val isPositive: Int => Status[Int] = 
  x => if (x > 0) x.success else s"$x not positive".failureNel

val isNegative: Int => Status[Int] = 
  x => if (x < 0) x.success else s"$x not negative".failureNel
```

I can write a new function `makeX`

```
case class X(x1: Int, // should be positive
             x2: Int, // should be positive
             x3: Int) // should be negative

val makeX: (Int, Int, Int) => Status[X] = (x1, x2, x3) => 
  (isPositive(x1) |@| isPositive(x2) |@| isNegative(x3)) (X.apply _)
```

My question is: How to write `makeX` in point-free style

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funky way to make it pointfree:

```
val makeX: (Int, Int, Int) => Status[X] = isPositive(_) |@| isPositive(_) |@| isNegative(_) apply X
```